# Convert SQL query to Active Record

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I need to query my database in Ruby on Rails using:

```
select p.name from shoppe_products p
join shoppe_product_categorizations ca on (p.id = ca.product_id)
join shoppe_product_categories c on (c.id = ca.product_category_id)
where c.id = 2
```

I use Ruby v 2.1.5, Rails v 4 and PG 9.4.

Comment: what are your models names?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need more information, like what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: If these map to models and those models have their relationships established then it is usually pretty easy to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply execute sql:

```
query_id = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(id_param)
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(
  "select p.name from shoppe_products p
  join shoppe_product_categorizations ca on (p.id = ca.product_id)
  join shoppe_product_categories c on (c.id = ca.product_category_id)
  where c.id = #{query_id}"
)
```

Without knowing your models etc this is best solution I can guess.

Comment: It would be better to use a prepared statement here rather than manually quoting the data.